# Hooks method AfterTestRun does not execute

Tags: specflow, nunit-3.0

Info of my tools & version set up are below

SpecFlow Version: 2.3
Used Test Runner:  NUnit
Version number: NUnit.ConsoleRunner v3.8.0; NUnit v3.10.1
Visual Studio Version: VS 2015
Are the latest Visual Studio updates installed? Yes
.NET Framework: >= .NET 4
Test Execution Method: Visual Studio Test Explorer TFS/VSTS

Issue Description:
On a project that I have been working on for more than 2 years now using SpecFlow automation, I recently discovered that the AfterTestRun method is not working; and it's not been working since May 2017. As I can see the clean up activities were executed in the results from that time; but have not been executing since then. At that time, we were using an earlier SpecFlow version but I am not sure which. However the issue is that BeforeTestRun and all other Hooks methods (BeforeFeature, BeforeScenario, BeforeStep, AfterStep, AfterScenario and AfterFeature) are working perfectly. Just the AfterTestRun method does not get executed at all. The final result compilation completes successfully but no traces of AfterTestRun having been executed.

I have searched through all relevant posts on the forum but have not been able to get any headway. i even installed SpecFlow.Nunit and SpecFlow.Nunit.Runner to see if that may be the issue (per one of the posts - but that too did not resolve the issue)